# Unusual path joining in python's os library

Tags: windows, python-3.4

I am trying this in Windows 8.1, with python v.3.4. The `os.path` module has a `join` method which, according to the documentation, is a safe way to join fragments of files or folders without mixing up back and forward slashes. In the code snippet below I am trying to join a file and a folder:-

```
>>> photo = r"\camera\picnic.jpg"
>>> folder = os.getcwd()
>>> print(folder)
C:\Users\Renae
>>> path = os.path.join(folder, photo)
>>> print(path)
C:\camera\picnic.jpg
```

And boom goes the dynamite. I was expecting path to be `C:\Users\Renae\camera\picnic.jpg`. I've tried removing the `r` in front of `photo` with no results. I've also tried backslashes even though Windows uses forward slashes which made it worse. The result was a mix of back and forward slashes. If I remember correctly this was not a problem in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the initial slash.

I can't speak for windows because it's been a long time since working on windows, but in *nix systems, starting a path with a slash signifies the root of the file system. I'm guessing that the implementation in python (and possibly more languages) use this convention on windows as well. I don't have a windows box to verify this on though.

Comment: The reason why I used `r` is to avoid cases like `folder\night\update.dat`. Here `\n` and `\u` will be wrongly interpreted by python's internal processing.

Comment: Ah of course, I forgot you're using backslashes -- my fault. Definitely remove the initial backslash though and you should be good to go.